# Latency difference between OpenAI API and AzureOpenAI API

Tags: azure, openai-api

Is there a latency difference between the OpenAI API and the AzureOpenAI API?
I've been using the OpenAI API for production systems, but I'm considering the AzureOpenAI API in terms of speed and reliability (the system must not go down).

From the tests I've conducted, I haven't noticed a significant difference in speed.
However, it seems reasonable to assume that the AzureOpenAI API, being directly managed by Microsoft, would be more stable. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out to us.

Please note that if you're utilizing the GPT4 model, then it is expected to see higher latency, given that GPT-4 has greater capacity compared to its predecessor, GPT-3.5.

As of now, we do not offer Service Level Agreements (SLAs) for response times from the Azure OpenAI service.

***Action Plan:***

If you want to improvise the latency of the Azure Open AI service response
then follow the steps mentioned in [***this article***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/how-to/latency#improve-performance). Hope this helps.